# How to display Javascript objects in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

I am spending significant time displaying objects in react.js and hope anybody help me.

I am trying to make my portfolio site. There is myprojects.js which has all of my projects listed. I want to showcase those projects with featured: true in the Projects page(projects.js) but somehow it is not successful.

Here is the projects.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap'
import { MYPROJECTS } from '../shared/myprojects'


function RenderCard(props) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardImg src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>{props.name}</CardTitle>
        <CardText>{props.description}</CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  )
}

class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      image: MYPROJECTS.image,
      name: MYPROJECTS.name,
      title: MYPROJECTS.title,
      caption: MYPROJECTS.description,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={this.state.image} name={this.state.name} caption={this.state.description} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={this.state.image} name={this.state.name} caption={this.state.description} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={this.state.image} name={this.state.name} caption={this.state.description} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}


export default Projects
```

This is the myprojects.js which I want to display in the projects.js.

```
export const MYPROJECTS = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply',
    image: '/assets/images/fake.jpg',
    elevation: 1233,
    featured: false,
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi porttitor ultricies dolor, id volutpat arcu. I',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ',
    image: '/assets/images/fake.jpg',
    elevation: 877,
    featured: true,
    description:
      'ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus maximus augue ut risus dictum, in tristique tellus convallis. Curabitur tristique ligula quam, vitae viverra nisl suscipit ut. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis pellentesque enim lorem, non interdum leo sollicitudin et. Mauris imperdiet tincidunt pellentesque. Aenean et vestibulum libero. Etiam id diam pulvinar, vestibulum velit nec, aliquam augue. Maece',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Praesent ut eros',
    image: '/assets/images/fake.jpg',
    elevation: 2901,
    featured: true,
    description:
      'nas eget nulla ut sem convallis lacinia nec et metus. Nullam bibendum maximus dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Duis nec finibus lorem. Phasellus tincidunt lorem est, vel egestas sapien convallis sed. .',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Duis gravida, lectus vel ',
    image: '/assets/images/fake.jpg',
    elevation: 42,
    featured: true,
    description:
      'In finibus nulla vitae ipsum cursus, quis lacinia lectus tincidunt. Curabitur ultricies vel nisl sit amet lacinia. Mauris in porttitor nisl, ut consectetur nunc..',
  },
]
```

Just in case, the main compornant(main.js) will be the parent for projects.js. This is the main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './header'
import Footer from './footer'
import Home from './home'
import Contact from './contact'
import Skills from './skills'
import Projects from './projects'
import Resume from './resume'
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class Main extends Component {
  
  render() {    
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/skills" component={Skills} />
          <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="/resume" component={Resume} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Redirect path="/home" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Main
```

Comment: MYPROJECTS is an array, yet you're trying to access single properties from them. In projects.js, if you changed things like `image: MYPROJECTS.image,` to `image: MYPROJECTS[0].image,`, maybe it'll start to work, and you'll at least see the first entry in the list. Use array.map() to show each item in the list: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Thanks so much for all of you. Scotty's explanation was very kind clear as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {MYPROJECTS} from 'MYPROJECTS'

////////////////////////////////
class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {MYPROJECTS.map(projects => (
            <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={projects.image} name={projects.name} caption={projects.description} />
            </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}


export default Projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Scotty mentioned MYPROJECTS is an array, heres a fixed render function

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          {MYPROJECTS.map(project => (
            <div className="row">
             <div className="col-md m-1">
               <RenderCard image={project.image} name={project.name} caption={this.state.description} />
             </div>
             <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={project.image} name={project.name} caption={this.state.description} />
             </div>
             <div className="col-md m-1">
              <RenderCard image={project.image} name={project.name} caption={project.description} />
             </div>
           </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
```